# Будет ли работать программа, скомпилированная с использованием OpenMP, на компьютере без поддержки OpenMP?

Tags: c, openmp

Будет ли работать программа, скомпилированная с использованием OpenMP (не статически), на компьютере без поддержки OpenMP? По идее если удалить все pragma omp, то код будет исполняться так же, т.е. параллельная и последовательная версии работают одинаково.

Comment: Скомпилированная "не статически" будет использовать библиотеки от OpenMP. И если их на целевой системе нет, то приложение даже не запуститься.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> параллельная и последовательная версии работают одинаково

Значит, программа как-то не так собралась. Или поддержка OpenMP таки отсутствует :)

> По идее если удалить все pragma omp

Прагмы - это ещё не всё. Сравним два бинарника, вот исходник:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
#pragma omp parallel
    printf( "Hello, OMP!\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Первый соберём без OpenMP:

```
$ gcc 1.c -o 1.bin && nm 1.bin

0000000000601040 B __bss_start
0000000000601040 b completed.6973
0000000000601030 D __data_start
0000000000601030 W data_start
0000000000400470 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000004004e0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000600e18 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000601038 D __dso_handle
0000000000600e28 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000601040 D _edata
0000000000601048 B _end
00000000004005c4 T _fini
0000000000400500 t frame_dummy
0000000000600e10 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000400708 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000601000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000004003e0 T _init
0000000000600e18 t __init_array_end
0000000000600e10 t __init_array_start
00000000004005d0 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000600e20 d __JCR_END__
0000000000600e20 d __JCR_LIST__
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
00000000004005c0 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000400550 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
000000000040052d T main
                 U puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000004004a0 t register_tm_clones
0000000000400440 T _start
0000000000601040 D __TMC_END__
```

Смотрим зависимости:

```
$ ldd 1.bin
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7e949000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1412f2e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1413325000)
```

А второй - с поддержкой:

```
$ gcc 1.c -o 2.bin -fopenmp && nm 2.bin

0000000000601050 B __bss_start
0000000000601050 b completed.6973
0000000000601040 D __data_start
0000000000601040 W data_start
0000000000400600 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000400670 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000600df8 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000601048 D __dso_handle
0000000000600e08 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000601050 D _edata
0000000000601058 B _end
0000000000400784 T _fini
0000000000400690 t frame_dummy
0000000000600df0 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
00000000004008f0 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000601000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
                 U GOMP_parallel_end@@GOMP_1.0
                 U GOMP_parallel_start@@GOMP_1.0
0000000000400548 T _init
0000000000600df8 t __init_array_end
0000000000600df0 t __init_array_start
0000000000400790 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000600e00 d __JCR_END__
0000000000600e00 d __JCR_LIST__
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000400780 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000400710 T __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000004006bd T main
00000000004006eb t main._omp_fn.0
                 U puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000400630 t register_tm_clones
00000000004005d0 T _start
0000000000601050 D __TMC_END__
```

И зависимости от библиотек:

```
$ ldd 2.bin
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff211fe000)
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f255034c000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f255012e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f254fd68000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f255058d000)
```

Соответственно, во втором случае библиотеки OpenMP нужны, и без них программа просто не запустится.

Comment: я бы показывал вывод ldd  и зависимость от библиотек.

Comment: @KoVadim, добавил.

Comment: Спасибо!
И небольшое уточнение: под одинаковостью работы имеется в виду, конечно же, одинаковый результат. К примеру, в случае с распараллеливанием цикла #pragma omp parallel for одинаковость работы эквивалентна отсутствию зависимостей между итерациями цикла.